# Using slider package in R to create new variable

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a new column in my dataset called "ResponseRecoded" which takes information based on another column.

The variable I'm trying to recoded is this, essentially I want the new column to just say "LEFT" or "RIGHT" conditionally based on whether someone made a left or right response 4 times (i.e. LEFT 1, LEFT 2, LEFT 3, LEFT 4 = LEFT):

```
 > MasterObjectAllocation$Response
   [1] NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          "enter"     "enter"     "enter"     NA         
  [10] "backspace" NA          "enter"     "enter"     "enter"     NA          "enter"     NA          "5"        
  [19] "right"     NA          "left"      "right"     "left"      NA          NA          NA          "LEFT 1"   
  [28] "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"  
  [37] "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA         
  [46] NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          NA         
  [55] NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"   
  [64] "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA         
  [73] NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"  
  [82] "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA         
  [91] NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"  
 [100] "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA         
 [109] NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"  
 [118] "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA         
 [127] NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"  
 [136] "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA         
 [145] NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"   
 [154] "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA         
 [163] NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"  
 [172] "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA         
 [181] NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"   
 [190] "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA         
 [199] NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"   
 [208] "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA         
 [217] NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"  
 [226] "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA         
 [235] NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"   
 [244] "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA         
 [253] NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"  
 [262] "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA         
 [271] NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"  
 [280] "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA         
 [289] NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"   
 [298] "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA         
 [307] NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"   
 [316] "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA         
 [325] NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"   
 [334] "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA         
 [343] NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"  
 [352] "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA         
 [361] NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"  
 [370] "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA         
 [379] NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"  
 [388] "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA         
 [397] NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"   
 [406] "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA         
 [415] NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"  
 [424] "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA         
 [433] NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"  
 [442] "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA         
 [451] NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"   
 [460] "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA         
 [469] NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"   
 [478] "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA         
 [487] NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"  
 [496] "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA         
 [505] NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"  
 [514] "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA         
 [523] NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"   
 [532] "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA         
 [541] NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"  
 [550] "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA         
 [559] NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"   
 [568] "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA         
 [577] NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"   
 [586] "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA         
 [595] NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"  
 [604] "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA         
 [613] NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"   
 [622] "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA         
 [631] NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"   
 [640] "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA         
 [649] NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          "right"     NA          "left"     
 [658] NA          "right"     NA          "left"      NA          NA          NA          NA          NA         
 [667] NA          NA          NA          "enter"     "enter"     "enter"     NA          "enter"     NA         
 [676] "5"         "left"      NA          "right"     "right"     "left"      NA          NA          NA         
 [685] "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"   
 [694] "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"   
 [703] NA          NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA         
 [712] NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "LEFT 1"   
 [721] "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"   
 [730] NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "LEFT 1"   
 [739] "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"  
 [748] NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"  
 [757] "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"  
 [766] NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"  
 [775] "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"   
 [784] NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"  
 [793] "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"   
 [802] NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"  
 [811] "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"   
 [820] NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"  
 [829] "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"   
 [838] NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "LEFT 1"   
 [847] "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"  
 [856] NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"  
 [865] "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"   
 [874] NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "LEFT 1"   
 [883] "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"  
 [892] NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "LEFT 1"   
 [901] "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"   
 [910] NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "LEFT 1"   
 [919] "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"   
 [928] NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "LEFT 1"   
 [937] "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"  
 [946] NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"   NA          NA          "LEFT 1"   
 [955] "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"  
 [964] NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "LEFT 1"   
 [973] "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "RIGHT 1"   "RIGHT 2"   "RIGHT 3"   "RIGHT 4"  
 [982] NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "LEFT 1"   
 [991] "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"    NA          NA          "LEFT 1"    "LEFT 2"    "LEFT 3"    "LEFT 4"   
[1000] NA         
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 48349 entries ]
```

The code I'm using is from the slider package:

```
MasterObjectAllocation$ResponseRecoded <- 
  sub("^([^ ]+) .*", "\\1", MasterObjectAllocation$Response) |>
  slider::slide_chr(
    \(x) if (length(x) > 3L && (all(x %in% "LEFT") || all(x %in% "RIGHT"))) x[[1L]] else NA_character_, 
    .before = 3L
  )
```

And the error I'm getting is this:

```
> MasterObjectAllocation$ResponseRecoded <- 
+   sub("^([^ ]+) .*", "\\1", MasterObjectAllocation$Response) |>
Error: unexpected '>' in:
"MasterObjectAllocation$ResponseRecoded <- 
  sub("^([^ ]+) .*", "\\1", MasterObjectAllocation$Response) |>"
>   slider::slide_chr(
+     \(x) if (length(x) > 3L && (all(x %in% "LEFT") || all(x %in% "RIGHT"))) x[[1L]] else NA_character_, 
Error: unexpected input in:
"  slider::slide_chr(
    \"
>     .before = 3L
>   )
Error: unexpected ')' in "  )"
>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What version of R are you using? If you want to use the native pipe `|>` you need at least 4.1. Looks like you might be using an older version.

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you :) That worked